# Is there a way to insert some lines between specific tag in a file

Tags: c#, streamwriter

I am trying to insert some lines between a specific location. So, for instance, I wanted to add Test between `<ID_1> ... </ID_1>`. How is it possible to add it and after I use it I wanted to delete that so that next time when I run I am entering new data. So far I know how can I add but I am entering in the last line of the file.

```
using (StreamWriter stream = File.AppendText(filename))
{
    stream.WriteLine("line1");
    stream.WriteLine("line2");
    stream.WriteLine("line3");
}
```

OutputFIle

```
<ID_1>

</ID_1>

<ID_2>

</ID_2>

<ID_3>

</ID_3>

<ID_4>

</ID_4>
```

Expected Output

```
<ID_1>
line1
line2
line3
</ID_1>

<ID_2>

</ID_2>

<ID_3>

</ID_3>

<ID_4>

</ID_4>
```

Comment: What you are looking for is to create a XML parser (or use an existing/ 3rd party libs out there). Refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/parsing-xml) for that

Comment: Is this XML? Use [`XDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xdocument?view=netframework-4.7.1) instead of `StreamWriter ` and you can insert text anywhere you want.

Comment: Dont manually parse and modify this structured data.  If this is XML, use the built in libraries in the framework.  If this is HTML, use HtmlAgilityPack.

Comment: @DourHighArch Yes its XML. Ya I will use XDocument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file is not a valid XML document. It should have a root-tag that encloses all the other tags. I named it `root` but any other name will do.

```xml
<root>
  <ID_1></ID_1>
  <ID_2></ID_2>
  <ID_3></ID_3>
  <ID_4></ID_4>
</root>
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(filename);
doc.Root.Element("ID_1").Value = "line1\r\nline2\r\nline3";
doc.Save(filename);
```

It will create a file that looks like this

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <ID_1>line1
line2
line3</ID_1>
  <ID_2></ID_2>
  <ID_3></ID_3>
  <ID_4></ID_4>
</root>
```

As you can see, a header line is added that makes it a well-formed XML-file.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't added a complete XML file. Whatever line it was supposed to be added in this post I have added only those part.

Answer (score 0):

Try this fiddle. Here I get `id` fron the tag and use some fake id-retrieval method

```
public static void Main()
{
    var xml = @"<doc><ID_1>
     </ID_1>
     <ID_2>
     </ID_2>
     <ID_3>
     </ID_3></doc>";

    XElement el = XElement.Parse(xml);
    foreach (var e in el.Elements())
    {
        var id = e.Name.LocalName.Split('_')[1];
        e.Value = GetLinesById(id);
    }
    Console.WriteLine(el.ToString());
}

private static string GetLinesById(string id)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    if (id == "1")
    {
        sb.AppendLine("Line 1");
    }
    else if (id == "2")
    {
        sb.AppendLine("Line 1");
        sb.AppendLine("Line 2");
    }
    else if (id == "3")
    {
        sb.AppendLine("Line 1");
        sb.AppendLine("Line 2");
        sb.AppendLine("Line 3");
    }

    return sb.ToString();

}
```

}

> `<doc>
>     <ID_1>Line 1
>   </ID_1>
>     <ID_2>Line 1
>   Line 2
>   </ID_2>
>     <ID_3>Line 1
>   Line 2
>   Line 3
>   </ID_3>
>   </doc>`